# Method gives different answer on different computers

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method which calculates the score of a certain route. On one computer this gives the correct result, but on another the result is off by a factor of around 36. Even with completely identical code bases, this still happens. The distances and order array are read from files, on both computers this file is the exact same. What could cause this error? I think it might be something to do with system settings, but I can't find any setting which would impact file parsing or addition of numbers. Code for the method with incorrect behaviour is attached below.

```
 public double CalculateScore()
 {
     double score = 0;

     for (int dag = 0; dag < 5; dag++)
     {
         for (int wagen = 0; wagen < 2; wagen++)
         {
             for (int trip = 0; trip < 3; trip++)
             {
                 if (mRoutes[wagen, dag, trip].mDictRoute.Count > 1)
                 {
                     int huidigeLocatieIndex = 0;
                     int volgendeLocatieIndex = 0;
                     
                     for (int i = 0; i < mRoutes[wagen, dag, trip].mDictRoute.Count; i++)
                     {
                         volgendeLocatieIndex = mRoutes[wagen, dag, trip].mDictRoute[huidigeLocatieIndex].Item2;

                         score += mDistances[mOrders[huidigeLocatieIndex].locatieId, mOrders[volgendeLocatieIndex].locatieId];
                         score += mOrders[volgendeLocatieIndex].duur;

                         huidigeLocatieIndex = volgendeLocatieIndex;
                         //volgendeLocatieIndex = mRoutes[wagen, dag, trip].mDictRoute[volgendeLocatieIndex].Item2;
                     }
                     score += /*mDistances[mOrders[huidigeLocatieIndex].locatieId, 0] +*/ 1800;
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     //Console.WriteLine("Score without penalty: {0}", score/60);

     for (int i = 0; i < mOrders.Length; i++)
     {
         if (mOrders[i].bezoeken < mOrders[i].frequentie)
         {
             score += 3 * mOrders[i].frequentie * mOrders[i].duur;
             //Console.WriteLine(3 * mOrders[i].frequentie * mOrders[i].duur);
         }
     }

     return (score/60.0f);
 }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

If you are using a hashset or dictionary to store items, then the order of them may change, which could affect e.g., a running total that depends on multiplication.

Comment: Culture settings could make an enormous difference - "1.5" could be read as "one point five" or "fifteen" depending on settings, for example...

Comment: Please include the code you use the parse the files and your numeric values. If you don't specify globalization in your parsing, the difference in the culture settings of the machine may account for the difference. Otherwise I don't see anything here that could explain the difference.

Comment: Possibly Floating-point error.  Try using a ``decimal`` instead of a ``double`` for score and ``(decimal)60.0`` and ``(decimal)1800`` to divide by.  With enough loops those errors will add up.

Comment: As pointed out already in the comments you need to provide an [mre] of the problem. Since this is most likely related to how your code *reads* the data (as it is very unlikely for pure function as shown in the question to produce vastly different results) make sure to include current culture (`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name`) of each machine where you observe the difference along with related *simplified* parsing code that still shows the problem while you [edit] the post.